# Designing a relationship with three entities where two entities have no relation

Tags: mysql, sql, entity-relationship, foreign-key-relationship, conceptual-model

Trying to implement an ER model where I have entities:teacher,student,papers and relationship: publishes,advises. Both teacher and student can publish a paper but only a teacher can advise a paper. Should I duplicate publishes relationship for both student and teacher or can I make it look like a three-way relationship with having no relationship between teacher and student?

Comment: If I try to implement such a database, will Papers table include two foreign keys from both teachers and students?

Comment: You need to better define your rules.  Can a paper be advised by only one teacher, or possibly multiple teachers?  Does a teacher advise students or only papers?  Does a paper published by a teacher also get advised by a teacher?  Do papers have multiple publishers (in real life, often an academic paper will have many names on it).

Comment: @Brian Yes, I should define my rules better. A paper can be published by many students and many teachers at the same time  and many advisers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you could model it like:

```
student(student_id, name, etc)
teacher(teacher_id, name, etc)
paper(paper_id, title, text, etc)
contributor(contributor_id, paper_id, contribution_type, contributor_type)
```

Where contribution type is an enum(publisher,adviser) and similarly contributor type is an enum(teacher,student)... or booleans is_publisher, is_adviser.

The drawback is that this doesn't permit foreign keys from contributor to student/teacher, and you don't have a rigid constraint from advisers to teachers.  A table adviser(teacher_id, paper_id) allows a constraint on the advisers, but still doesn't allow constraints or foreign keys on student ids.

Another options might be to break it up as:

```
teacher_contribution(teacher_id, paper_id, is_adviser)
student_contribution(student_id, paper_id)
```

which would allow completely constraining the database to the intended model, but could be more difficult to query in some situations.

Any are acceptable.  It depends to some extent on your particular application and how you intend to query the data.

Comment: I prefer the 2nd approach for most tasks, as it makes DRI easier (even if doing some logic on a role discriminator column like `is_advisor`). Views can often take care of the "I wish I used a single link table so this query was easier" situations.

Comment: i tend to go further and call each a PERSON, then there is a PERSON_PAPER association with a role enumeration..

Comment: @Randy I tend to have the person link up on the "other" side - e.g. students and teachers can still all be people. Although, that suggestion seems good here - what if a person is no longer a student? They have *still* authored the paper. (I primarily deal with "snapshot" data-sets.)

Comment: exactly, a PERSON is only a STUDENT for some time period, but could always be associated to the PAPER later.  Plus, why restrict the number of authors, and reviewers etc...